# Delegated POS (DPOS) vs Proof of Stake (POS): Specified Differences

Tags: proof-of-stake

Delegated POS (DPOS) vs Proof of Stake (POS) -- May I know what are the specified Differences?

Answer (score 1):

Proof of Stake allow you to directly participate in consensus, if you have enough stake and the system is open.

DPOS as implemented in EOS allows coin holders to vote in block producers who then run consensus rules.

An improvement over DPOS is liquid proof of stake (LPOS) as implemented in Tezos.

Tezos allows anyone with 10k coins to bake (validate) blocks proportional to their share of the network stake.

LPOS is also more inclusive by allowing those who don't wish to run their own nodes, or who have less than 10k coins, to delegate to other bakers (validators) who then run consensus and do pay outs for the rights to validate blocks.

LPOS allows a large portion of the total network to be involved in consensus.