# Delegated Proof of Stake (DPOS) vs. Proo of Stake?

Tags: blockchain, security, proof-of-stake, consensus

What is the **main difference** between `Delegated Proof of Stake (DPOS)` vs. `Proof of Stake`? Is there any significant advantage for **security**? (since PoS in general suffers security problems.) And **which** **DLTs** / **Blockchains** use `DPOS`?

P.S. A similar question asked [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/55141/23024), but without any answer.

**Update:** According to answer of user vaz, my opinion is as follows:

We can say that in `DPOS` **additional validators** promote **delegated validators**. This could lead to make delegated validators **more powerful** and as a result **more centralized consensus**. Becasue we have **fewer** and **more powerful** validators. In my opinion, this even **decrease security** against **failure** and also **rebellion of validators**. However, it would be **faster** thanks to being **more centralized**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the main difference is that DPOS provides a way to allow more participants in the consensus process, while improving scalability. The additional participants, however, do not participate directly in the consensus process: they only vote for a delegated validator node.

The only advantage I can see in terms of security is that, by having fewer , more powerful validator nodes, one can establish a minimum level of security standard/infrastructure. But this comes at the cost of centralisation.

BLockchains using DPOS include EOS, Tezos and Lisk.

Comment: Thank you, So we can say that briefly in DPOS additional validators **promote** delegated validators. This could lead to make delegated validators more powerful and as a result more centralized consensus. Becasue we have fewer and more powerful validators. In my opinion, this even decrease security against failure and also rebellion of validators. However, it would be faster thanks to **being more centralized**.